# Calling APP Functions outside of app?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm a beginner Android developer so sorry if this sounds stupid but I'm trying to figure out how to call a function of my app or to call the app outside of app itself. What I mean is, say that you're playing a game, talking to friends or watching a movie. I was wondering what approach I would use in order to solve my problem?

Also, I was wondering how I can get my app to appear in the notifications panel persistently (such as that it's online kind of like BBM).

Any help wold be greatly appreciated,
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) in your app and declare it in the manifest so that other apps with a specific intent-filter can call and initiate your service. It is also possible to have the service running in the forefront (like how Facebook messenger works)

I don't know about persistent notifications, but you should check out [Push Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) in general. You can easily create one within the app. Possibly monitor if it is dismissed and re-initiate it?